# facebook php sdk select images friends

Tags: php, html, mysql, facebook, sdk

I'm trying the facebook sdk but I need help being the first time that I use it. I would like in my div every time I load the page appears a profile picture of my friends at random. How can I do?

Comment: why do you want to load profile picture of your friend? Exactly what functionality you have to implement? Provide some code u have written.

Comment: I do not have a reason to upload photos of friends. I'm doing some tests, I started a few days ago with the facebook sdk I was wondering if it was possible to do such a thing

Comment: you can use graph api to get profile pic of user.
http://graph.facebook.com/[user_id]/picture
ex. http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture